# swift 3 what is better form?

Tags: variables, swift3, variable-declaration

I was wondering what is the better way to declare variables?

```
private var arrayOfStrings: [String] = []
```

or

```
private var arrayOfStrings = [String]()
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of either solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322) there are little differences in the 2 ways.
Using `type annotation` you declare which type the variable is, while not using it you let Swift infer the type of the variable.

Almost always Swift will infer the correct type. Be careful:
[image]
As you can encounter situations like this in which Swift will have a decision to take. Read the full documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Comment: so the difference ist only the type inference? nothing memory management related or something else?

Comment: No, as Swift infers the type as soon as you assign a value to the variable